# Greater or less sign in python appears when this code is executed

Tags: python, mysql, phpmyadmin, temperature

I am trying to insert python data into a mysql table. I am using a ds18b20 temperature sensor. I have tried many tutorials but I cannot understand how to add mysql into a python code used for obtaining temperature data. Any help would be appreciated! I've now updated my code and the indent error is gone. But, when I execute this code, nothing happens and the greater or less than python(>>>) sign is the only thing that generates when executing my code.

Here is the python :

```
import os
import glob
import time
import MySQLdb
import datetime

i = datetime.datetime.now()

db = MySQLdb.connect(host = "localhost", user = "root", passwd = "test", db = "temp_pi")
cur = db.cursor()

os.system('modprobe w1-gpio')
os.system('modprobe w1-therm')

base_dir = '/sys/bus/w1/devices/'
device_folder = glob.glob(base_dir + '28*')[0]
device_file = device_folder + '/w1_slave'

def read_temp_raw():
    f = open(device_file, 'r')
    lines = f.readlines()
    f.close()
    return lines

def read_temp():
    lines = read_temp_raw()
    while lines[0].strip()[-3:] != 'YES':
        time.sleep(0.2)
        lines = read_temp_raw()
    equals_pos = lines[1].find('t=')
    if equals_pos != -1:
        temp_string = lines[1][equals_pos+2:]
        temp_c = float(temp_string) / 1000.0
        temp_f = temp_c * 9.0 / 5.0 + 32.0
        return temp_c
    while True:
          print ("recording data into database(period = 5s.)....press ctrl+Z to stop!")

          valT = str(read_temp())

          year = str(i.year)
          month = str(i.month)
          day = str(i.day)
          date = day + "-" + month + "-" + year

          hour = str(i.hour)
          minute = str(i.minute)
          second = str(i.second)
          time = hour + ":" + minute + ":" + second

          try:
             cur.execute("""INSERT INTO TAB_CLASSROOM(temp_c,T_Date,T_Time) VALUES(%s,%s,%s)""",(valT,date,time))
             db.commit()
          except:
             db.rollback()

          time.sleep(10)

    cur.close()  
    db.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import os
import glob
import time
import MySQLdb
import datetime

i = datetime.datetime.noW()

db = MySQLdb.connect(host = "localhost", user = "root", passwd = "test", db = "temp_pi")
cur = db.cursor()

os.system('modprobe w1-gpio')
os.system('modprobe w1-therm')

base_dir = '/sys/bus/w1/devices/'
device_folder = glob.glob(base_dir + '28*')[0]
device_file = device_folder + '/w1_slave'

def read_temp_raw():
    f = open(device_file, 'r')
    lines = f.readlines()
    f.close()
    return lines

def read_temp():
    lines = read_temp_raw()
    while lines[0].strip()[-3:] != 'YES':
        time.sleep(0.2)
        lines = read_temp_raw()
    equals_pos = lines[1].find('t=')
    if equals_pos != -1:
        temp_string = lines[1][equals_pos+2:]
        temp_c = float(temp_string) / 1000.0
        temp_f = temp_c * 9.0 / 5.0 + 32.0
        return temp_c
    while True:
          print("recording data into database(period = 5s.)....press ctrl+Z to stop!")

          valT = str(read_temp())

          year = str(i.year)
          month = str(i.month)
          day = str(i.day)
          date = day + "-" + month + "-" + year

          hour = str(i.hour)
          minute = str(i.minute)
          second = str(i.second)
          timestring = hour + ":" + minute + ":" + second

          try:
             cur.execute("""INSERT INTO TAB_CLASSROOM(temp_c,rec_time,rec_date) VALUES(%s,%s,%s)""",(valT,timestring,date))
             db.commit()
          except:
             db.rollback()

          time.sleep(10)

cur.close()
db.close()
```

according to my editor your WHILE statement is not indented properly.  Depending on the version of pythonm, 2.7 or 3.X, you may if it is 3.x need () around the print statement after the while.

Comment: while True:
          print ("recording data into database(period = 5s.)....press ctrl+Z to stop!")

Comment: Is this what you meant since it still gives me the same error.

Comment: Not exactly.  print("recording data into database(period = 5s.)....press ctrl+Z to stop!") no space between print and (

Comment: There were a few errors, I fixed most of them; you never use the tempf variable.

Comment: Thanks! The error is gone! But now when I execute the program nothing happens. So therefore I am confused to why. @Shenanigator

Comment: I can't really help you there since I don't have access to the backend.  If this helped please mark the answer correct.

Comment: Some other page helped me figure that part out but you helped me figure out something so thank you! Sure I'll give you the checkmark. What does that do for you lol? @Shenanigator

Comment: It adds rep for both of us.